# Changes made to a copied image makes the changes to original image too.(js)

Tags: javascript

I copied an image and made changes to it. Somehow the original image also getting changes too, which shouldn't be.
Does anybody know how to fix it?

[Text](https://codepen.io/wlcs/pen/rNaOLzN?editors=0010)

```
<script>
var thePhoto;
var theImage = null;
var theCanvas = null;
function upload(){
  thePhoto = document.getElementById("orgPhoto");
  theImage = new SimpleImage(thePhoto);
  theCanvas = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
  theImage.drawTo(theCanvas);
}
function makeGray(){
  if (theCanvas == null || ! theCanvas.complete()){
    alert('no photo');
  }else{
    var GrayImage = new SimpleImage(thePhoto);
    for (var pixel of GrayImage.values()){
      var avg = (pixel.getRed()+pixel.getGreen()+pixel.getBlue())/3;
      pixel.setRed(avg);
      pixel.setGreen(avg);
      pixel.setBlue(avg);
    }
    GrayImage.drawTo(theCanvas);
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: After applying changes when I click the rest button, I get the original image. I cannot understand your problem. Please elaborate.

Comment: same variable used for canvas  theImage = new SimpleImage(thePhoto);

Comment: I just solve the problem. I add the var GrayImage&RainbowImage&RedImage  in the function upload();
So I don't need to using var "theImage" to doing filter

Comment: But I'm not sure is it about the "global var" and "domain var" problem.

Answer (score 0):

i dont get what all this for but by simply doing this you would get grey image on the canvas

```
thePhoto = document.getElementById("orgPhoto");
  theCanvas = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
  var ctx = theCanvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.filter='grayscale(100%)';
  ctx.drawImage(thePhoto, 20,20);
```